# Equation of the parabola enclosing a scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting

I have the x and y coordinates of the following graph as two different lists s and k. If I want to determine the equation of the parabola that best encloses these points, how do I do it?

[image]

Thanks!

I am not sure how to link to an external data set.

[What is the best way to add your dataset to a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250975/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-your-dataset-to-a-question)

This was the best I could find. So, I am putting up a sample data set here. I will be removing this later, though.

```
                K             S
0    9.500000e-01 -6.500000e-01
1    8.500000e-01 -6.000000e-01
2    9.000000e-01 -6.000000e-01
3    9.500000e-01 -6.000000e-01
4    7.000000e-01 -5.500000e-01
5    7.500000e-01 -5.500000e-01
6    8.000000e-01 -5.500000e-01
7    8.500000e-01 -5.500000e-01
8    9.000000e-01 -5.500000e-01
9    9.500000e-01 -5.500000e-01
10   6.000000e-01 -5.000000e-01
11   6.500000e-01 -5.000000e-01
12   7.000000e-01 -5.000000e-01
13   7.500000e-01 -5.000000e-01
14   8.000000e-01 -5.000000e-01
15   8.500000e-01 -5.000000e-01
16   9.000000e-01 -5.000000e-01
17   9.500000e-01 -5.000000e-01
18   5.000000e-01 -4.500000e-01
19   5.500000e-01 -4.500000e-01
20   6.000000e-01 -4.500000e-01
21   6.500000e-01 -4.500000e-01
22   7.000000e-01 -4.500000e-01
23   7.500000e-01 -4.500000e-01
24   8.000000e-01 -4.500000e-01
25   8.500000e-01 -4.500000e-01
26   9.000000e-01 -4.500000e-01
27   9.500000e-01 -4.500000e-01
28   4.000000e-01 -4.000000e-01
29   4.500000e-01 -4.000000e-01
30   5.000000e-01 -4.000000e-01
31   5.500000e-01 -4.000000e-01
32   6.000000e-01 -4.000000e-01
33   6.500000e-01 -4.000000e-01
34   7.000000e-01 -4.000000e-01
35   7.500000e-01 -4.000000e-01
36   8.000000e-01 -4.000000e-01
37   8.500000e-01 -4.000000e-01
38   9.000000e-01 -4.000000e-01
39   9.500000e-01 -4.000000e-01
40   3.000000e-01 -3.500000e-01
41   3.500000e-01 -3.500000e-01
42   4.000000e-01 -3.500000e-01
43   4.500000e-01 -3.500000e-01
44   5.000000e-01 -3.500000e-01
45   5.500000e-01 -3.500000e-01
46   6.000000e-01 -3.500000e-01
47   6.500000e-01 -3.500000e-01
48   7.000000e-01 -3.500000e-01
49   7.500000e-01 -3.500000e-01
50   8.000000e-01 -3.500000e-01
51   8.500000e-01 -3.500000e-01
52   9.000000e-01 -3.500000e-01
53   9.500000e-01 -3.500000e-01
54   2.000000e-01 -3.000000e-01
55   2.500000e-01 -3.000000e-01
56   3.000000e-01 -3.000000e-01
57   3.500000e-01 -3.000000e-01
58   4.000000e-01 -3.000000e-01
59   4.500000e-01 -3.000000e-01
60   5.000000e-01 -3.000000e-01
61   5.500000e-01 -3.000000e-01
62   6.000000e-01 -3.000000e-01
63   6.500000e-01 -3.000000e-01
64   7.000000e-01 -3.000000e-01
65   7.500000e-01 -3.000000e-01
66   8.000000e-01 -3.000000e-01
67   8.500000e-01 -3.000000e-01
68   9.000000e-01 -3.000000e-01
69   9.500000e-01 -3.000000e-01
70   1.000000e-01 -2.500000e-01
71   1.500000e-01 -2.500000e-01
72   2.000000e-01 -2.500000e-01
73   2.500000e-01 -2.500000e-01
74   3.000000e-01 -2.500000e-01
75   3.500000e-01 -2.500000e-01
76   4.000000e-01 -2.500000e-01
77   4.500000e-01 -2.500000e-01
78   5.000000e-01 -2.500000e-01
79   5.500000e-01 -2.500000e-01
80   6.000000e-01 -2.500000e-01
81   6.500000e-01 -2.500000e-01
82   7.000000e-01 -2.500000e-01
83   7.500000e-01 -2.500000e-01
84   8.000000e-01 -2.500000e-01
85   8.500000e-01 -2.500000e-01
86   9.000000e-01 -2.500000e-01
87   9.500000e-01 -2.500000e-01
88   5.000000e-02 -2.000000e-01
89   1.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01
90   1.500000e-01 -2.000000e-01
91   2.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01
92   2.500000e-01 -2.000000e-01
93   3.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01
94   3.500000e-01 -2.000000e-01
95   4.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01
96   4.500000e-01 -2.000000e-01
97   5.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01
98   5.500000e-01 -2.000000e-01
99   6.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01
100  6.500000e-01 -2.000000e-01
101  7.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01
102  7.500000e-01 -2.000000e-01
103  8.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01
104  8.500000e-01 -2.000000e-01
105  9.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01
106  9.500000e-01 -2.000000e-01
107  8.881784e-16 -1.500000e-01
108  5.000000e-02 -1.500000e-01
109  1.000000e-01 -1.500000e-01
110  1.500000e-01 -1.500000e-01
111  2.000000e-01 -1.500000e-01
112  2.500000e-01 -1.500000e-01
113  3.000000e-01 -1.500000e-01
114  3.500000e-01 -1.500000e-01
115  4.000000e-01 -1.500000e-01
116  4.500000e-01 -1.500000e-01
117  5.000000e-01 -1.500000e-01
118  5.500000e-01 -1.500000e-01
119  6.000000e-01 -1.500000e-01
120  6.500000e-01 -1.500000e-01
121  7.000000e-01 -1.500000e-01
122  7.500000e-01 -1.500000e-01
123  8.000000e-01 -1.500000e-01
124  8.500000e-01 -1.500000e-01
125  9.000000e-01 -1.500000e-01
126  9.500000e-01 -1.500000e-01
127 -5.000000e-02 -1.000000e-01
128  8.881784e-16 -1.000000e-01
129  5.000000e-02 -1.000000e-01
130  1.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01
131  1.500000e-01 -1.000000e-01
132  2.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01
133  2.500000e-01 -1.000000e-01
134  3.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01
135  3.500000e-01 -1.000000e-01
136  4.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01
137  4.500000e-01 -1.000000e-01
138  5.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01
139  5.500000e-01 -1.000000e-01
140  6.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01
141  6.500000e-01 -1.000000e-01
142  7.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01
143  7.500000e-01 -1.000000e-01
144  8.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01
145  8.500000e-01 -1.000000e-01
146  9.000000e-01 -1.000000e-01
147  9.500000e-01 -1.000000e-01
148 -1.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02
149 -5.000000e-02 -5.000000e-02
150  8.881784e-16 -5.000000e-02
151  5.000000e-02 -5.000000e-02
152  1.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02
153  1.500000e-01 -5.000000e-02
154  2.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02
155  2.500000e-01 -5.000000e-02
156  3.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02
157  3.500000e-01 -5.000000e-02
158  4.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02
159  4.500000e-01 -5.000000e-02
160  5.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02
161  5.500000e-01 -5.000000e-02
162  6.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02
163  6.500000e-01 -5.000000e-02
164  7.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02
165  7.500000e-01 -5.000000e-02
166  8.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02
167  8.500000e-01 -5.000000e-02
168  9.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02
169  9.500000e-01 -5.000000e-02
170 -1.500000e-01  8.881784e-16
171 -1.000000e-01  8.881784e-16
172 -5.000000e-02  8.881784e-16
173  8.881784e-16  8.881784e-16
174  5.000000e-02  8.881784e-16
175  1.000000e-01  8.881784e-16
176  1.500000e-01  8.881784e-16
177  2.000000e-01  8.881784e-16
178  2.500000e-01  8.881784e-16
179  3.000000e-01  8.881784e-16
180  3.500000e-01  8.881784e-16
181  4.000000e-01  8.881784e-16
182  4.500000e-01  8.881784e-16
183  5.000000e-01  8.881784e-16
184  5.500000e-01  8.881784e-16
185  6.000000e-01  8.881784e-16
186  6.500000e-01  8.881784e-16
187  7.000000e-01  8.881784e-16
188  7.500000e-01  8.881784e-16
189  8.000000e-01  8.881784e-16
190  8.500000e-01  8.881784e-16
191  9.000000e-01  8.881784e-16
192  9.500000e-01  8.881784e-16
193 -2.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
194 -1.500000e-01  5.000000e-02
195 -1.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
196 -5.000000e-02  5.000000e-02
197  8.881784e-16  5.000000e-02
198  5.000000e-02  5.000000e-02
199  1.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
200  1.500000e-01  5.000000e-02
201  2.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
202  2.500000e-01  5.000000e-02
203  3.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
204  3.500000e-01  5.000000e-02
205  4.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
206  4.500000e-01  5.000000e-02
207  5.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
208  5.500000e-01  5.000000e-02
209  6.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
210  6.500000e-01  5.000000e-02
211  7.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
212  7.500000e-01  5.000000e-02
213  8.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
214  8.500000e-01  5.000000e-02
215  9.000000e-01  5.000000e-02
216  9.500000e-01  5.000000e-02
217 -2.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
218 -1.500000e-01  1.000000e-01
219 -1.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
220 -5.000000e-02  1.000000e-01
221  8.881784e-16  1.000000e-01
222  5.000000e-02  1.000000e-01
223  1.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
224  1.500000e-01  1.000000e-01
225  2.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
226  2.500000e-01  1.000000e-01
227  3.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
228  3.500000e-01  1.000000e-01
229  4.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
230  4.500000e-01  1.000000e-01
231  5.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
232  5.500000e-01  1.000000e-01
233  6.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
234  6.500000e-01  1.000000e-01
235  7.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
236  7.500000e-01  1.000000e-01
237  8.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
238  8.500000e-01  1.000000e-01
239  9.000000e-01  1.000000e-01
240  9.500000e-01  1.000000e-01
241 -1.500000e-01  1.500000e-01
242 -1.000000e-01  1.500000e-01
243 -5.000000e-02  1.500000e-01
244  8.881784e-16  1.500000e-01
245  5.000000e-02  1.500000e-01
246  1.000000e-01  1.500000e-01
247  1.500000e-01  1.500000e-01
248  2.000000e-01  1.500000e-01
249  2.500000e-01  1.500000e-01
250  3.000000e-01  1.500000e-01
251  3.500000e-01  1.500000e-01
252  4.000000e-01  1.500000e-01
253  4.500000e-01  1.500000e-01
254  5.000000e-01  1.500000e-01
255  5.500000e-01  1.500000e-01
256  6.000000e-01  1.500000e-01
257  6.500000e-01  1.500000e-01
258  7.000000e-01  1.500000e-01
259  7.500000e-01  1.500000e-01
260  8.000000e-01  1.500000e-01
261  8.500000e-01  1.500000e-01
262  9.000000e-01  1.500000e-01
263  9.500000e-01  1.500000e-01
264 -1.000000e-01  2.000000e-01
265 -5.000000e-02  2.000000e-01
266  8.881784e-16  2.000000e-01
267  5.000000e-02  2.000000e-01
268  1.000000e-01  2.000000e-01
269  1.500000e-01  2.000000e-01
270  2.000000e-01  2.000000e-01
271  2.500000e-01  2.000000e-01
272  3.000000e-01  2.000000e-01
273  3.500000e-01  2.000000e-01
274  4.000000e-01  2.000000e-01
275  4.500000e-01  2.000000e-01
276  5.000000e-01  2.000000e-01
277  5.500000e-01  2.000000e-01
278  6.000000e-01  2.000000e-01
279  6.500000e-01  2.000000e-01
280  7.000000e-01  2.000000e-01
281  7.500000e-01  2.000000e-01
282  8.000000e-01  2.000000e-01
283  8.500000e-01  2.000000e-01
284  9.000000e-01  2.000000e-01
285  9.500000e-01  2.000000e-01
286 -5.000000e-02  2.500000e-01
287  8.881784e-16  2.500000e-01
288  5.000000e-02  2.500000e-01
289  1.000000e-01  2.500000e-01
290  1.500000e-01  2.500000e-01
291  2.000000e-01  2.500000e-01
292  2.500000e-01  2.500000e-01
293  3.000000e-01  2.500000e-01
294  3.500000e-01  2.500000e-01
295  4.000000e-01  2.500000e-01
296  4.500000e-01  2.500000e-01
297  5.000000e-01  2.500000e-01
298  5.500000e-01  2.500000e-01
299  6.000000e-01  2.500000e-01
300  6.500000e-01  2.500000e-01
301  7.000000e-01  2.500000e-01
302  7.500000e-01  2.500000e-01
303  8.000000e-01  2.500000e-01
304  8.500000e-01  2.500000e-01
305  9.000000e-01  2.500000e-01
306  9.500000e-01  2.500000e-01
307  8.881784e-16  3.000000e-01
308  5.000000e-02  3.000000e-01
309  1.000000e-01  3.000000e-01
310  1.500000e-01  3.000000e-01
311  2.000000e-01  3.000000e-01
312  2.500000e-01  3.000000e-01
313  3.000000e-01  3.000000e-01
314  3.500000e-01  3.000000e-01
315  4.000000e-01  3.000000e-01
316  4.500000e-01  3.000000e-01
317  5.000000e-01  3.000000e-01
318  5.500000e-01  3.000000e-01
319  6.000000e-01  3.000000e-01
320  6.500000e-01  3.000000e-01
321  7.000000e-01  3.000000e-01
322  7.500000e-01  3.000000e-01
323  8.000000e-01  3.000000e-01
324  8.500000e-01  3.000000e-01
325  9.000000e-01  3.000000e-01
326  9.500000e-01  3.000000e-01
327  5.000000e-02  3.500000e-01
328  1.000000e-01  3.500000e-01
329  1.500000e-01  3.500000e-01
330  2.000000e-01  3.500000e-01
331  2.500000e-01  3.500000e-01
332  3.000000e-01  3.500000e-01
333  3.500000e-01  3.500000e-01
334  4.000000e-01  3.500000e-01
335  4.500000e-01  3.500000e-01
336  5.000000e-01  3.500000e-01
337  5.500000e-01  3.500000e-01
338  6.000000e-01  3.500000e-01
339  6.500000e-01  3.500000e-01
340  7.000000e-01  3.500000e-01
341  7.500000e-01  3.500000e-01
342  8.000000e-01  3.500000e-01
343  8.500000e-01  3.500000e-01
344  9.000000e-01  3.500000e-01
345  9.500000e-01  3.500000e-01
346  1.500000e-01  4.000000e-01
347  2.000000e-01  4.000000e-01
348  2.500000e-01  4.000000e-01
349  3.000000e-01  4.000000e-01
350  3.500000e-01  4.000000e-01
351  4.000000e-01  4.000000e-01
352  4.500000e-01  4.000000e-01
353  5.000000e-01  4.000000e-01
354  5.500000e-01  4.000000e-01
355  6.000000e-01  4.000000e-01
356  6.500000e-01  4.000000e-01
357  7.000000e-01  4.000000e-01
358  7.500000e-01  4.000000e-01
359  8.000000e-01  4.000000e-01
360  8.500000e-01  4.000000e-01
361  9.000000e-01  4.000000e-01
362  9.500000e-01  4.000000e-01
363  2.000000e-01  4.500000e-01
364  2.500000e-01  4.500000e-01
365  3.000000e-01  4.500000e-01
366  3.500000e-01  4.500000e-01
367  4.000000e-01  4.500000e-01
368  4.500000e-01  4.500000e-01
369  5.000000e-01  4.500000e-01
370  5.500000e-01  4.500000e-01
371  6.000000e-01  4.500000e-01
372  6.500000e-01  4.500000e-01
373  7.000000e-01  4.500000e-01
374  7.500000e-01  4.500000e-01
375  8.000000e-01  4.500000e-01
376  8.500000e-01  4.500000e-01
377  9.000000e-01  4.500000e-01
378  9.500000e-01  4.500000e-01
379  3.000000e-01  5.000000e-01
380  3.500000e-01  5.000000e-01
381  4.000000e-01  5.000000e-01
382  4.500000e-01  5.000000e-01
383  5.000000e-01  5.000000e-01
384  5.500000e-01  5.000000e-01
385  6.000000e-01  5.000000e-01
386  6.500000e-01  5.000000e-01
387  7.000000e-01  5.000000e-01
388  7.500000e-01  5.000000e-01
389  8.000000e-01  5.000000e-01
390  8.500000e-01  5.000000e-01
391  9.000000e-01  5.000000e-01
392  9.500000e-01  5.000000e-01
393  4.000000e-01  5.500000e-01
394  4.500000e-01  5.500000e-01
395  5.000000e-01  5.500000e-01
396  5.500000e-01  5.500000e-01
397  6.000000e-01  5.500000e-01
398  6.500000e-01  5.500000e-01
399  7.000000e-01  5.500000e-01
400  7.500000e-01  5.500000e-01
401  8.000000e-01  5.500000e-01
402  8.500000e-01  5.500000e-01
403  9.000000e-01  5.500000e-01
404  9.500000e-01  5.500000e-01
405  5.000000e-01  6.000000e-01
406  5.500000e-01  6.000000e-01
407  6.000000e-01  6.000000e-01
408  6.500000e-01  6.000000e-01
409  7.000000e-01  6.000000e-01
410  7.500000e-01  6.000000e-01
411  8.000000e-01  6.000000e-01
412  8.500000e-01  6.000000e-01
413  9.000000e-01  6.000000e-01
414  9.500000e-01  6.000000e-01
415  6.000000e-01  6.500000e-01
416  6.500000e-01  6.500000e-01
417  7.000000e-01  6.500000e-01
418  7.500000e-01  6.500000e-01
419  8.000000e-01  6.500000e-01
420  8.500000e-01  6.500000e-01
421  9.000000e-01  6.500000e-01
422  9.500000e-01  6.500000e-01
423  7.500000e-01  7.000000e-01
424  8.000000e-01  7.000000e-01
425  8.500000e-01  7.000000e-01
426  9.000000e-01  7.000000e-01
427  9.500000e-01  7.000000e-01
428  8.500000e-01  7.500000e-01
429  9.000000e-01  7.500000e-01
430  9.500000e-01  7.500000e-01
```

Comment: This is just a theory, but you could take discrete points on a parabola, and at first make it pretty much flat. The, increase the gradient untik a certain number of points are within a certain boundary.

Comment: Could you put up a link to your data to work with?

Comment: I have put up a sample data set. Is there no easier way? There has to be.

Comment: Sure. You can link to a site like dtpaste. At any rate, I'm working on your question with sample data of my own.

Comment: The hard part is actually defining "best". I can't see that there is a natural definition. Additionally, depending on your data source, you might also consider relaxing the "enclosed" parts (e.g. data from physical measurements might produce outliers).

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: I just saw your answer. For my data set, it returns x**2/122. Could you elaborate on your logic a little more?

Comment: Also, I am just thinking, wouldn't it be easier to try get the coordinates of the outermost points and plot a curve that passes through those points?

Comment: The increments in x as 0.05. What if I find the minimum y value for each x and find the best curve passing through these points? How would I write out my program in this case? I could feed the lists into a dataframe and work around with it.

Comment: One sec. I assumed that you only had a parabola. Give me a few minutes and I'll sort it.

Comment: I can't get the data to work on my computer. Could you dpaste me a link to only the positive s and k variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172228/discussion-between-3141-and-hegdep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution requires some iterations but seems to work most of the time. In same occasions, however, it gets stuck with the parabola on the wrong side, sometimes the opening seems by far too wide. But if the input data is as dense as the image of the OP suggests ( in contrast to my random input data ), this is probably avoided.

The example uses parabolas of type `a + b * x**2` but adding a linear term is no problem.

Code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from random import random
from scipy.optimize import leastsq, curve_fit, fmin
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import warnings
np.set_printoptions( precision = 5 )

def parabola( x, a, b, c ):
    return a + b * x + c * x**2

### find the shortest distance between a given point and a parabola
### actually give x such as ( x, f(x) ) is closest to ( x0, y0 )
def orth_dist( x0, y0, a, b, c ):
    f = lambda x: np.sqrt( ( x - x0 )**2 + ( parabola( x, a, b, c ) - y0 )**2 )
    sol = fmin( f, x0, disp=False )
    return sol[ 0 ]

### cost function: standard distance if point is above parabola
### or extra cost if point is below
def myDist( r, dy , off=4e0 ):
    out =  abs( r )
    if dy <= 0:
        out = max( [out, off + off * abs( r)  ] )
    return out

def residuals( p, data, off=0 ): # data is of type [ [x0,y0], [x1,y1],... ] 
    xList, yList = zip( *data )
    ### a standard fit uses the distance in y direction between curve and 
    ### data point. Here it is better to use the shortest distance.
    ### To find the shortest distance some extra numerics is required.
    xopt = [ orth_dist( x0, y0, *p ) for x0, y0 in zip( xList, yList ) ]
    yopt = [ parabola( x, *p ) for x in xopt ]
    yFitList = [ parabola( x, *p ) for x in xList ]
    rList = [ np.sqrt( ( x - x0 )**2 + (y - y0 )**2 ) for x, x0, y , y0 in zip( xList, xopt, yList, yopt ) ]
    signList = [ y - yTh  for y, yTh in zip( yList, yFitList ) ]
    out = [ myDist( r, dy , off=off ) for r, dy in zip( rList, signList ) ]
    return out

### removing the upper points of the convex hull
### as it is convex, it can be at most a straight line 
### from the most left to the most right point
### if a point of the hull is on or above this line, dump it
def remove_upper( data ):
    sortedByX = sorted( data)
    xList, yList = zip( *sortedByX )
    m = ( yList[-1] - yList[0] ) / ( xList[-1] - xList[0] )
    out = [ sortedByX[0] ]
    for p in range( 1, len(data ) ):
        x = xList[ p ]
        y = yList[ p ]
        if y < m * ( x - xList[0]) + yList[0]:
            out += [ sortedByX[ p ] ]
    out += [ sortedByX[ -1 ] ]
    return out

### my choice of 'true' parameters
myParameters = ( .45, -1.3, 2.33)

### just some random data for testing
scatterData = list()
for i in range(180):
    x = 3*( 2 * random() - 1) + 1.1
    y = 8 * random()
    if y > parabola( x, *myParameters ):
        scatterData += [ [ x, y ] ]

### to fit the parabula we do not need inner points, 
### so let's take the convex hull
hull = ConvexHull(scatterData )
scatterDataHull = list()
for index in hull.vertices:
    scatterDataHull += [ scatterData[ index ] ]

### the upper points of the convex hull are also useless 
#### if not disturbing, so get rid of them as well 
scatterDataHullR = remove_upper( scatterDataHull )

### exact data for plotting
xxList = np.linspace( -4, 4, 300 )
yyList = [ parabola( x, *myParameters ) for x in xxList ]

scatterX, scatterY =zip(*scatterDataHullR)

start, pcov = curve_fit( parabola,  *zip(*scatterDataHullR) )

fit = list( start )
counter = 0
test = True
myOff = .1
while test:
    counter += 1
    ### "simple" fit with orthogonal distance
    fit, err = leastsq( residuals, x0=fit, args=( scatterDataHullR, myOff ) )
    ### as points below the parabola are forbidden, we give those a high
    ### cost in the fitting. Starting with very high costs, however, 
    ### results in bad convergence. So we start with a rather low cost,
    ### check if some points are below and---if so---increase the cost.
    ### We then fit again with the previous result as starting point.
    ### (Note sometimes this fails, but I did not have time to
    ### investigate this cases. Moreover I hope that this is due 
    ### to my quite random points, while the points in the OP look 
    ### by for more regular.)
    print "fit",fit 
    xList, yList = zip( *scatterDataHullR )
    yFitList = [ parabola( x, *fit ) for x in xList ]
    signList = [ y - yTh  for y, yTh in zip( yList, yFitList ) ]
    print counter, myOff
    print signList
    if min( signList ) < 0:
        myOff *= 2
    else:
        test = False
    if counter > 50: # maxiter
        test = False
        warnings.warn( "Max iterations reached.", UserWarning )

startList = [ parabola( x, *start ) for x in xxList ]
fitList = [ parabola( x, *fit ) for x in xxList ]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( xxList, yyList , label='true parabula')
ax.plot( xxList, startList, label='simple fit' )
ax.plot( xxList, fitList, label='result')
ax.scatter( *zip( *scatterData ), s=60, label='full data')
ax.scatter( *zip( *scatterDataHull ), s=40, label='convex hull')
ax.scatter( *zip( *scatterDataHullR ), s=20, label='lower hull' )
ax.legend( loc=0 )
ax.set_xlim( [ -2, 5 ] )
ax.set_ylim( [ 0, 10 ] )
plt.show()
```

Output is:

```
>>fit [ 0.62572 -1.75611  2.81445]
>>1 0.1
>>[0.6213711303862084, 0.18684681979766804, -0.30967646606163246, -0.146185783279136, 1.5115384666142262e-08, 0.04091503213347902, -0.22456258154469477, -0.10366901944547369]
>>fit [ 0.6484  -1.80986  2.75176]
>>2 0.2
>>[0.62199186259362, 0.17515271586535786, -0.34273136096659584, -0.17923227341075365, 9.718855165097295e-10, 0.057645756995909014, -0.10363664705794662, 0.13933840419257315]
>>fit [ 0.6484  -1.80986  2.75176]
>>3 0.4
>>[0.62199186259362, 0.17515271586535786, -0.34273136096659584, -0.17923227341075365, 9.718855165097295e-10, 0.057645756995909014, -0.10363664705794662, 0.13933840419257315]
>>fit [ 0.53489 -1.56037  2.54129]
>>4 0.8
>>[1.3184522612014575, 0.7674472388911582, -0.021666294928952112, 0.025470161835318805, 0.056401815047789794, 0.10025191012633528, 2.6445583856116173e-07, 0.4250810523461581]
>>fit [ 0.51566 -1.53254  2.53166]
>>5 1.6
>>[1.3836247162551256, 0.8254553204503852, 0.016315167888327764, 0.0536843248273029, 0.06793421458085641, 0.10848235358916569, 2.42328743738085e-08, 0.42471967128564003]
```

and

[image]

Comment: Could you explain your code a little more? It does seem really neat. There are many things I'm seeing for the first time.

Comment: @hegdep I added several comments to the code. I hope that helps. If you have further questions, let me know.

Comment: I follow the curve fitting part much better now. However, how do you determine the initial equation of the parabola to be `parabola( x, .45, 2.33 )`? In my case, I have two lists and I want to determine the initial equation of the parabola.

Comment: @hegdep OK, in my case that's just my random choice and I stick to it. In your case I'd chose 3 points that make a parabola unique; say most left, most right and lowest point ( hoping that those conditions do not coincide). From this you could determine a starting parabola.

Comment: @hegdep you could also take the most left most right and a third one from the reduced convex hull. I'd actually make a simple curve_fit to the reduced convex hull. If the values are in the range of 1, which seems to be the case, it should work without initial guess. You can then take the result of that fit as starting point for the iteration.

Comment: I get it, it does seem to work brilliantly now. However, I might be doing something silly. When I try to define my parabola in the form `y=ax^2+bx+c` it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @hegdep I updated it for 3 parameters, but note that it is `a + b * x +  c * x**2`, i.e. the other way around to what you defined.

Comment: @ mikuszefski Thanks! It works like a charm. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code out. It approximates the parabola through trial and error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
s = list([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
k = list([0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64]) #Insert Data Here(positive side only)

def parab(x):
    for f in range(0,len(s)): 
        v = f**2/(x/2)
        yield v

def parab2():
    t = 201
    for i in range(0,200):
        g = 0
        t-=1
        foo = np.fromiter(parab(t), dtype = 'int')
        for bar in range(0,len(s)):
            if foo[bar] < k[bar]+0.5 and foo[bar] > k[bar]-0.5:
                g += 1
        if g >= len(s)/2:
            print(foo)
            print("x**2/",t/2)

parab2()
```

Try it. If it approximates to roughly for you try fiddling around with what x^2 is divided by.

Also, as your dataset size increases, try to increase the value in the line
`if g>=4:`

You can decide on which size works best for you.

**EDIT** Updated code: this works better.