# Removing a tab every nth column from pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to access a column of a data frame I created out of two lists and do some filtering. However, there seems to be an additional space for every 12th element in my dataframe. How do I deal with this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'S': s,
     'K': k})
```

I created the dataframe with the code as above. Also, for some weird reason, it was stored in scientific notation with type float. I used df.round(4) before I could actually figure out what the problem was.

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-2e289598b460> in <module>()
----> 1 df[df['S']]

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1956         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   1957             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 1958             return self._getitem_array(key)
   1959         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   1960             return self._getitem_frame(key)

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2000             return self.take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   2001         else:
-> 2002             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2003             return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   2004 

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1229                 mask = check == -1
   1230                 if mask.any():
-> 1231                     raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
   1232 
   1233                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: '[-0.65 -0.6  -0.6  -0.6  -0.55 -0.55 -0.55 -0.55 -0.55 -0.55 -0.5  -0.5\n -0.5  -0.5  -0.5  -0.5  -0.5  -0.5  -0.45 -0.45 -0.45 -0.45 -0.45 -0.45\n -0.45 -0.45 -0.45 -0.45 -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4\n -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.35 -0.35 -0.35 -0.35 -0.35 -0.35 -0.35 -0.35\n -0.35 -0.35 -0.35 -0.35 -0.35 -0.35 -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.3\n -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.3  -0.25 -0.25\n -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25\n -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2\n -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.2  -0.15\n -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15\n -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.15 -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1\n -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1\n -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.1  -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05\n -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05 -0.05\n -0.05 -0.05  0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.\n  0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.\n  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05\n  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05  0.05\n  0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1\n  0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1   0.1\n  0.1   0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15\n  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15  0.15\n  0.15  0.15  0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2\n  0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2   0.2\n  0.2   0.2   0.2   0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25\n  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25\n  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.25  0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3\n  0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3\n  0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.3   0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35\n  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35\n  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.35  0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4\n  0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4\n  0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45\n  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45\n  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.45  0.5   0.5   0.5\n  0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5\n  0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.55  0.55  0.55\n  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55\n  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.55  0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6\n  0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6\n  0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.6   0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65\n  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.65\n  0.65  0.65  0.65  0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7\n  0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.7   0.75\n  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75\n  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.75  0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8\n  0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8   0.8   0.85  0.85\n  0.85  0.85  0.85  0.85  0.85  0.85  0.85  0.85  0.85  0.85  0.85  0.85\n  0.85  0.9   0.9   0.9   0.9   0.9   0.9   0.9   0.9   0.9   0.9   0.9\n  0.9   0.9   0.95  0.95  0.95  0.95  0.95  0.95  0.95  0.95  0.95  0.95\n  0.95  1.    1.    1.    1.    1.    1.    1.    1.    1.    1.05  1.05\n  1.05  1.05  1.05  1.05  1.1   1.1   1.1   1.1   1.15  1.3   1.3   1.3\n  1.3   1.3   1.35  1.35  1.35  1.35  1.35  1.35  1.35  1.35  1.35  1.35\n  1.4   1.4   1.4   1.4   1.4   1.4   1.4   1.4   1.4   1.4   1.4   1.4\n  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45\n  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45  1.45] not in index'
```

Comment: Were the spaces already in your lists and how did you create those two lists?

Comment: There are no spaces in the lists when I print them out. The generation of the lists is a little complex. They were generated using for loops and looking for certain conditions on a couple of lists and appended only if elements of the lists passed these criteria.

Comment: Could you share how you created the dataframe?

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove every `\n` in `S` like so:

```
df["S"] = df["S"].apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace("\n", "")))
```

But by the way: `df[df["S"]]` will look for the values of `S` in the index. With your construction of the dataframe, there will probably not be any value of `S` in the index.

Comment: Try `df[df["S"] == 0.65]`

Comment: My bad! That is what I tried. It returns an empty df

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638823/equation-of-the-parabola-enclosing-a-scatter-plot

Comment: The dataframe is in the link above. Basically, I want to find the minimum value of k at each value of s.

Comment: What data type is `df["S"]` now?

Comment: `df.dtypes` returns`S    float64
K    float64
dtype: object`

Comment: Hm, then it seems that the value is not in your data frame. Try `df["S"].value_counts()` to get a quick overview of all the values in the column and see if 0.65 is really in there or if you have any values that you can't find.

Comment: `df["S"].value_counts() ` returns `6.500000e-01    21`. Even when I try `df[df["S"] == 6.500000*e**-01]` it returns an empty data frame.