# Linear regression minimizing errors only above the linear

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, least-squares

I have a dataset that resembles the data created in the MWE below:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sz=100
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, sz)
mean = -np.sign(x)
noise = np.random.randn(*x.shape)
K = -2

y_true = K*x
y = y_true + mean + noise

plt.scatter(x, y, label="Data with error")
plt.plot(x, y_true, "-", label="True line")
plt.grid()
```

[image]

That is, the errors around the line I want are mostly negative for x>0 and mostly positive for x<0. What I'm looking for is a way to estimate the coefficient K (which in this case is -2).

Really I think the way to do it would be to minimize the error only of the points that fall above the line for x<0 and below the line for x>0, but I'm not sure how to go about it effectively in Python, since everything I can think of involves iterative processes which are slow in Python.

Comment: My first thought is that this will not work. An algorithm will find a large negative slope such that all points for `x<0` will lie below and all point for `x>0` will lie above. This would result in zero error with your approach, but is definitively not what you want.

Comment: If you know the reason or the mechanism for the asymmetric error, however, you can code this into an asymmetric weight function, not zero on one side, though.

Comment: @mikuszefski Yes, I think you're right. It will converge to error zero, which is not what I want. Do you know of any approach that could take into consideration the skewness of the error (assuming I know it)?

Comment: ...for sure there are statistical methods...or you could try to implement an asymmetric error weighting in a least square method.

Comment: it is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56038624/803359), only that you do not go down to zero. Here you can   make the slope part of your chi test. Something like: find the smallest slope such that the errors... This requires a subjective weighting, though.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to include something that can account for the `mean` variable in your data generating model. You can do this by modeling a discontinuity at the point x=0 by including a variable in your model that is 0 where x < 0 and 1 where x > 0.

We can even just include the "mean" variable itself and get the same model (with a different interpretation for the second coefficient). Here is a linear model that recovers the correct value for the slope of this discontinuous line. Note that this assumes the slope is the same on the right side of 0 as the left side.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.array([x, mean]).T
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
print(reg.coef_)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, isn't that just a regular least squares fit? (`a*x+b`)?

Comment: Yes, this is just a regular least squares fit. The first coefficient represents the slope of the line you're looking for (e.i. K) if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. If you look at the figure you'll see that a least squares fit would not recover the orange line.

Comment: It will if you include a variable that captures the discontinuity at x=0. Try running that model I posted with a larger sample size (e.g. 10,000), and you'll see that the first coefficient converges to -2

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt where I A) fit all data to a straight line, and then B) separate data depending on two criteria: whether x is greater than or less than zero and whether predicted Y is above or below that straight line, and finally C) fit the separated data. The slope is here -2.417 and will vary from run to run depending on the random data.

[image: plot]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sz=100
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, sz)
mean = -np.sign(x)
noise = np.random.randn(*x.shape)
K = -2

y_true = K*x
y = y_true + mean + noise

plt.scatter(x, y, label="Data with error")
plt.plot(x, y_true, "-", label="True line")

###############################
# new section for calculatiing new line
allDataFirstOrderParameters = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
allDataFirstOrderErrors = y - np.polyval(allDataFirstOrderParameters, x)

newX = []
newY = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] < 0 and allDataFirstOrderErrors[i] < 0:
        newX.append(x[i])
        newY.append(y[i])
    if x[i] > 0 and allDataFirstOrderErrors[i] > 0:
        newX.append(x[i])
        newY.append(y[i])

newX = np.array(newX)
newY = np.array(newY)

newFirstOrderParameters = np.polyfit(newX, newY, 1)
print("New Parameters", newFirstOrderParameters)

plotNewX = np.linspace(min(x), max(x))
plotNewY = np.polyval(newFirstOrderParameters, plotNewX)
plt.plot(plotNewX, plotNewY, label="New line")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```